# Add tabs to a view-page

Tags: views

What I want to achieve is rather simple but either I haven't drank enough coffee yet or Google is boycotting the wanted results :)

I have a view ("the view"), of type "page" , formatted and styled exactly the way I want it; all is good.

Using the [Weight module](http://drupal.org/project/weight) I have created another view ("the sorter"), also a page, with which to sort "the view".

What I'd like to do is to add 2 tabs, above both views, one leading the "the view's" url and one leading to "the sorter's" url, for easy back and forth transitions from the sorting mechanism to the front-end.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Of course I want only the administrators to see those tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. For "the view" you should add a menu style default menu tab with View URL: `example.com/view/the-view` and a parent menu item with URL: `example.com/view`.
2. For "the sorter" you should add a menu tab menu item and have the View URL be `example.com/view/the-sorter`.

This is easier to do than to explain. You might need to fiddling around to get it, but this is the gist of it.

Comment: I can't seem to add any url, anywhere. Requesting further elaboration please.

Comment: Also, isn't there a way to add 'irrelevant' links to the tab menu such as 'Add new item' where item would be another node of the content type "the view" is associated with?

Comment: @magtak I added SS of how it looks in Drupal 7 Views 3.  I believe Views 2 also has this option, but it's probably placed elsewhere.

Comment: I've been fiddling with this, managed to get some tabs to show, the 2nd one (menu tab type) shows and works perfectly.

For the 1st one to show the only configuration that works is "default menu item" and as Parent item the 2nd radio: "Parent Item". But the tab's url is that of the parent item instead of the view's. Very confusing feature...

Comment: @magtak Views uses the core menu system which is why it can be a bit confusing. You need to setup the view page URLs and menu urls correct to make it work. I tried to explain a bit more detailed, if you keep trying you should get it to work eventually :)

Comment: got it working after all btw, was kinda weird, needed a normal menu item for the view itself, one default tab for the view itself (again), and one tab for the sorter. whoa!

Comment: @googletorp: Is it possible to add tabs to a view without the need to set a default menu entry for the whole view? http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94421/how-to-create-a-tabbed-view-in-a-panel-without-a-menu-entry